# Align text by baseline in FPDF

Tags: php, pdf-generation, fpdf, typography, baseline

I am using the following code to display a headline and a date next to each other using FPDF:

```
$this->SetFont('Helvetica', 'B', 30);
$this->Cell(120, 20, 'Rechnung 20130809-78');

$this->SetFont('Helvetica', '', 10);
$this->Cell(0, 20, '09. 08. 2013');
```

But the texts are not aligned properly:

[image: The date is to high.]

How can I get it to work so that the baselines are on the same height?

I do not want a solution where I have to adjust the position of one of the elements manually. It has to work with every font-size I enter.

I already have tried to adjust the y-position automatically in my Cell-method, but the text is then not aligned at the baselines but at the bottom (where the g ends)!

```
public function Cell($w, $h=0, $txt='', $border=0, $ln=0, $align='', $fill=false, $link='') {
    $text = utf8_decode($txt);

    $startX = $this->GetX();
    $startY = $this->GetY();

    $this->SetY($startY - $this->FontSize / 2);
    $this->SetX($startX);

    parent::Cell($w, $h, $txt, $border, $ln, $align, $fill, $link);

    $endX = $this->GetX();
    $endY = $this->GetY();

    $this->SetY($startY);
    $this->SetX($endX);
}
```

[image: They are aligned at the bottom instead of the baseline.]

Is there any way to do what I intend to do? Please help me! The green lines in the image above should be at the same height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
function drawTextBox($strText, $w, $h, $align='L', $valign='T', $border=true)
{
        $xi=$this->GetX();
        $yi=$this->GetY();

        $hrow=$this->FontSize;
        $textrows=$this->drawRows($w,$hrow,$strText,0,$align,0,0,0);
        $maxrows=floor($h/$this->FontSize);
        $rows=min($textrows,$maxrows);

        $dy=0;
        if (strtoupper($valign)=='M')
                $dy=($h-$rows*$this->FontSize)/2;
        if (strtoupper($valign)=='B')
                $dy=$h-$rows*$this->FontSize;

        $this->SetY($yi+$dy);
        $this->SetX($xi);

        $this->drawRows($w,$hrow,$strText,0,$align,false,$rows,1);

        if ($border)
                $this->Rect($xi,$yi,$w,$h);
}
```

source: https://github.com/lsolesen/fpdf/blob/master/examples/textbox/textbox.php

There is also an addon for that: http://fpdf.de/downloads/addons/52/